# <Select> dropdown is getting displayed far away from input when using transform: scale on parent Iframe

Tags: html, css, forms, iframe, css-transforms

I have some select dropdown lists in a bootstrap page.

The bootstrap page is displayed inside of an iframe.

When I use the transform:scale CSS property on the iframe, the dropdown list get displayed far away from the select input.
It's look like it's displayed where the select would have been if I wasn't using transform: scale, it's displayed correctly when I remove transform: scale.(but I really need it)

I'm using Firefox 115 on a Macbook Pro M1 Catalina v12.2.1.

It looks like this:
[image: Here is how it's rendered:]

The CSS of the iframe looks like this:

```
.iframe-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  transform: scale(0.6666667);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

The iframe looks like this:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe src="/editor.html" style="height: 150vh;" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

The select input looks like this: (it's inside editor.html)

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">How to handle large text:</span>
              </div>
              <select id="fit-type" class="form-control">
                <option selected="selected">fit</option>
                <option>ellipsis</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Is it a (known?) bug? Or expected behavior? Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks